# How to create an overload method with a rest parameter?

Tags: typescript, overloading

A declaration of external library types is given. I quote used parts from it:

```
interface IRouterMatcher<T> {
    (path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]): T;
    (path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandlerParams[]): T;
}

interface IRouterHandler<T> {
    (...handlers: RequestHandler[]): T;
    (...handlers: RequestHandlerParams[]): T;
}


interface IRouter extends RequestHandler {
    // ...
    use: IRouterHandler<this> & IRouterMatcher<this>;
    // ...
}
```

Based on this declaration, I need to create a class with the use() method.
It clearly shows that you need to create an overload method.
I tried to do this as follows:

```
export default class Router extends RequestHandler {
    // ...
    use(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]): this
    use(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandlerParams[]): this
    use(...handlers: RequestHandler[]): this
    use(...handlers: RequestHandlerParams[]): this {
        // ...
        return this;
    }
    // ...
}
```

On what has received such error:

```
error TS2394: Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.
```

How do I correctly create a use() method?

Answer (score 0):

When you use a rest parameter, the TypeScript compiler generates the following JS code in the beginning of your function:

```
var handlers = [];
for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
    handlers[_i] = arguments[_i];
}
```

This code is reading from the implicit `arguments` object, and cannot on its own detect whether the first argument is a `PathParams` or a `RequestHandler` or `RequestHandlerParams`.

However, we can do this ourselves by having the actual implementation of these overloads take no parameters and reading `arguments` manually:

```
use(): this {
    let path: PathParams;
    let indexOffset = 0;
    if (isPathParams(arguments[0])) {
        path = arguments[0];
        indexOffset = 1;
    }
    let handlers: RequestHandler[] | RequestHandlerParams[] = [];
    for (var i = indexOffset; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        handlers[i - indexOffset] = arguments[i];
    }
    // ...
    return this;
}
```

(I'm using a helper type guard `function isPathParams(obj: any): obj is PathParams` in this example to assert the correct type.)